# CORS error on React app with Active Directory plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, active-directory, dynamics-crm, adal

I am getting error `401` or CORS related error when fetching the [Active Directory plugin through its own plugin for React ([React-ADAL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal)).

I have to integrate the Active Directory Web API plugin with my React.js App to be able to fetch data from my Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM platform.

According to [Micosoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/oauth-cross-origin-resource-sharing-connect-single-page-application) the ADAL plugin facilitates this CORS stuff but I still see this CORS error while fetching with `adalApiFetch()` function.

This is my `adalConfig.js` file:

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
    tenant: '<tenant id>',
    clientId: '<active directory app id>',
    endpoints: {
        api: '<active directory app id>'
    },
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) => adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, fetch, url, options);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api);
```

And then my `Component` code to fetch with the plugin:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../../adalConfig';

export default class AComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLeads();
    }

    getLeads() {
        let result;
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers
        };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, 'https://myorg.crm2.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/leads', options)
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('SERVER ERROR:', error));
    }
}
```

My Chrome's developer tools displays:

[image]

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server has to be configured to tell client browsers that it's OK to make requests from different domains. That apparently is not the case for the server you're trying to access.

Comment: It's not just a server, it is an Online platform: maybe a [reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/220117)

Comment: The browser does not know the difference between a "server" and an "online platform". Whatever responds to the HTTP request has to obey the protocol.

Comment: Okay... so, what do you suggest?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what needs to be done to the host you're trying to talk to. The key is that responses to incoming HTTP requests should be given those headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` mostly) so that the browser will not generate that error. It's a basic web security feature. Every server-side platform has its own way of doing that, so it'd be something the CRM platform would support somehow. You can't address the problem from the client side of the interaction, or else the security measure would be worthless.

Comment: [Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873822/how-to-enable-cors-in-dynamics-crm) — there's also a lot of results if you just google for "Microsoft Dynamics CRM CORS"

Comment: Regarding the previous comment, I have enabled `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header before it didn't work. I will try after enabling CORS on Dynamics (I am able to).

Comment: I read I have to edit the server side code, but even the CRM Administrators don't have access to these fatures, but the Microsoft IT agents can.